# Reading Barcode with PyQt: Why is the class reading the input twice?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Last week I had a problem with the PyQt5 and reading the barcode. The problem is solved. Now I've another problem. I can read the barcode, but my input is always twice. So before I end the program, the program goes into the class "check.status" twice before it quits the program.

Is there any way to count the inputs or just to wait until the input is right? Maybe with try-except?

This is my current coding:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QWidget
import sys 

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Seriennummer")
        self.setFixedSize(250, 100)
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.set_sn()
        self.show()
               
    def set_sn(self):
        self.sn_Textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.sn_Textbox.move(85, 35)
        self.sn_Textbox.resize(130, 20)
        self.sn_Textbox.setMaxLength(7)
        self.sn_Textbox.setPlaceholderText("Seriennummer")
        self.sn_Textbox.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.onlyInt = QIntValidator()
        self.sn_Textbox.setValidator(self.onlyInt)
        self.sn_Textbox.editingFinished.connect(self.checkstatus)

    def checkstatus(self):
        self.inp_sn = self.sn_Textbox.text()
        
        print("Check")
        
        if len(self.inp_sn) ==  7 and self.inp_sn.isdigit():
            print("Your Text: ", self.sn_Textbox.text())
            self.close()

        else:
            print(self.inp_sn)
            print("Wrong input")
            self.error_msg()

    def error_msg(self):
        msg_error = QMessageBox()
        msg_error.setWindowTitle("Error message")
        msg_error.setText("Wrong input: Überprüfe Seriennummer")
        msg_error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        
        x = msg_error.exec()
        
def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    
    sys.exit(App.exec())
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've put a printf()-function to see the output and so you can also see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) points out:

> **[void QLineEdit::editingFinished()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished)**
> This signal is emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus. Note that if there is a validator() or inputMask() set on the line edit and enter/return is pressed, the editingFinished() signal will only be emitted if the input follows the inputMask() and the validator() returns QValidator::Acceptable.

The editingFinished signal is emitted for several reasons, in your case it is emitted 2 times: the first by the endline (`\n`) and the second when the QLineEdit loses focus. So a possible solution is to check if the widget has the focus (use `hasFocus()`). But in this case it is better to use the returnPressed signal:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QWidget


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Seriennummer")
        self.setFixedSize(250, 100)
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.set_sn()

    def set_sn(self):
        self.barcode_le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.barcode_le.setGeometry(85, 35, 130, 20)
        self.barcode_le.returnPressed.connect(self.handle_returnPressed)
        self.barcode_le.setMaxLength(7)
        self.barcode_le.setPlaceholderText("Seriennummer")
        self.barcode_le.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        validator = QIntValidator()
        self.barcode_le.setValidator(validator)

    def handle_returnPressed(self):
        text = self.barcode_le.text()
        if len(text) == 7 and text.isdigit():
            print("Your Text: ", text)
            self.close()
        else:
            print(text)
            print("Wrong input")
            self.error_msg()

    def error_msg(self):
        msg_error = QMessageBox()
        msg_error.setWindowTitle("Error message")
        msg_error.setText("Wrong input: Überprüfe Seriennummer")
        msg_error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        x = msg_error.exec()


def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(App.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Works fine. And it's well-aranged also for a beginner. My question is: What is the big difference to your edited code with the class "BarcodeLineEdit" where u get the event and the status. More compact?

Comment: @PYlearning09 It is the same, only that I realized that there was already a signal that detected the endline so it was unnecessary to do the same work